# Two Meteor Sites Real Time Updates

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to have an update on siteA  respond on siteB in an icon. Example: Discuss icon number changing real time from siteA to siteB if it originally came from siteA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with some work. This is my idea:

Assuming you are running two separate apps, I would maintain a collection that keeps track of whatever you want. Then when that thing changes on siteA, you can make an HTTP request to siteB. I would set up an API endpoint using [server-side routing with Iron Router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#restful-routes) and maybe some security features if pertinent.

In summary, I would set up a RESTful API to communicate the changes between your two sites.

Comment: Please do not answer blatantly off-topic questions (here, way too broad and lacking an MCVE). It makes it look like it is okay to ask such questions, the question may get closed and deleted and your work will be for naught.